# Text emphasis classes color not changing on customisation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm currently running a fork of a Bootstrap 3 theme. I have run into a small roadblock, and I would like some help.
I have changed the `@brand-∗` variables, but the text emphasis classes `(.text-*;)` aren't picking up the new colors except for `.text-primary` and `.text-muted`, the rest inherit the default text color which is `#fff`.
 Before, the classes were manually redefined using the new colors, I thought that the color would change like I expected but I couldn't figure out why.
You can find the code here: https://github.com/wolfy1339/m8tro-bootstrap/tree/master/src/themes/m8tro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't overide the correct variables.

Look at [type.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less)

You see :

```
.text-primary {
  .text-emphasis-variant(@brand-primary);
}
.text-success {
  .text-emphasis-variant(@state-success-text);
}
.text-info {
  .text-emphasis-variant(@state-info-text);
}
.text-warning {
  .text-emphasis-variant(@state-warning-text);
}
.text-danger {
  .text-emphasis-variant(@state-danger-text);
}
```

`.text-emphasis-variant` is a mixin coded in [/mixins/text-emphasis.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/text-emphasis.less)

So you just have to override this variables you can find [Form states and alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#form-states-and-alerts)